# Getting ElementNotFound Exception in TestNG

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng

The following code is for login and then click on Create quest Link. It does not click on the link and gives ElementNotFound exception and skips the test. It just logs in and logout. Please Help

```
public class Edit_Question {

    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();@
    BeforeTest
    public void load() {
    driver.get("Page url");
    }

    @  Test
    public void login() throws InterruptedException {
    driver.findElement(By.id("userid")).sendKeys("4060@jhg.com");
    driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("mpcyn2");
    driver.findElement(By.id("emLoginLink")).click();
    Thread.sleep(10000);
    }@  Test
    public void ques() throws InterruptedException {
    //select create questions
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//xpath link")).click(); //throws        ElementNotFound exception
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    }@  Test
    public void logout() {
    //logout
    driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("SeeharackTest1, SherrodUATT")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("logoutLink")).click();
    }

    @   AfterSuite
    public void close() {
    driver.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: what's your HTML for test web page? does XPATH LINK reaches the desired DOM node?

Answer (score 1):

The order of execution is not gauranteed.  You need to use dependOnMethods to gaurantee order here.  So ques should depend on login and logout should depend on ques to gaurantee the order of execution.

Other observations :
1. Try using @BeforeClass instead of @BeforeTest and @AfterClass instead of @AfterSuite
2. Avoid using sleeps wherever possible.  Wait for a particular element instead.
3. Shouldn't this entire flow be one testcase?

Hope it helps.

Comment: I have tried implementing your suggestions. But I am still getting the same error. I changed the Classpath a few days ago for ANT build.xml. Could this error be because of that?

Comment: No changing classpath shouldn't be related to this.  Can you paste your updated code.